AWS hosted (Route 53) domains, no DNS propagation / Attempting to change DNS resigtrar to CF
I have a pool of 10 domains that were originally hosted through AWS Route 53.
Initially I had two of the domains configured with appropriate DNS records, for AWS EC2 web servers.
Unexpectedly, two days ago none the sites would serve in the browser, but instead 'Page can't be found' along with DNS related errors.
I spent a couple of days in the log to try and resolve the issue, had no luck.
Spent time debugging and tweaking configs in an attempt to get the project back up and moving to no avail, and ultimately have attempted to change the NS from AWS to Cloudflare.
This change was made  over 24 hours ago. Almost immediately, AWS indicated the NS records were updated on for all of the domains in question. However, Cloudflare still shows Pending NS Update (same status for all domains in the group). And it appears no nameservers or any DNS records for these websites is listed anyway on the web at all.
2 examples of the impacted AWS/Route53 hosted domains:

seclink.au
securelink.net.au

Additional information:

Hosted Zones on Route53: Initially one existed for each of the domains. After AWS indicated the NS update was complete, I figured they were no longer required as this can be managed in CloudFlare. I have deleted them from Route53.

Registered domains

Screenshot from Route53 Registered Domains

AWS DNS status for domains in question - "Name server update successful" - 2 DAYS AGO



Hello? Is anybody out there?

It appears things are configured correctly, so at this point I'd contact CF support.

Changing nameservers does not change your registrar. The registrar is one level higher up than the nameservers – it is what submits your nameserver choice to the "registry" (the TLD administrator).
Currently WHOIS says that your registrar has indeed submitted the NS updates to the registry (it lists two CF nameservers for both domains).
However, both of your domains are also reported by WHOIS as being in the clientHold and serverHold status, which means that their nameserver delegations are deliberately not published in DNS for whatever reason.
In other words, it is not a DNS problem but more likely a business problem. Contact your registrar (which you say should be AWS, although it is listed as "Instra" in WHOIS) or the registry (auDA).
(The clientHold flag is set by the registrar, while serverHold is set by the registry; I'm not sure in which situations both would be present.)
